# Apache Solr indexing xml-File over http with XPathEntityProcessor

Tags: apache, solr

I have a problem and did not find any solution. 
I'm searching for the best way to index a lot of Notes-DBs.
One way is, that my DB generates an XML file after I send a request to the REST web service with my browser and it works.

I downloaded the file and imported it over the Admin-Console with the update request and File-Upload.
It works. My schema is managed (I have too many fields to do this manually).

But i don't know how to handle this with `XPathEntityProcessor`. 
How should the `data-config.xml` look like for my solution?

Many thanks for your help. I'm almost desperate.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution. It works when I have the fields previously added in managed-schema (with updateRequestHandler and managed-schema is no need to do this). Tested with a simple xml-File.
`

```
<dataConfig>
         <dataSource type="URLDataSource" />
        <document> 
                  <entity name="xml"
                      processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                      url="http://path/to/test.xml"                       
                      useSolrAddSchema="true"
                      stream="true"
                      connectionTimeout="120000"
                      readTimeout="300000">
                   </entity>
         </document>
    </dataConfig>`
```

Now, the log says that i have "only" a problem with connectionTimeout.